# Как сохранить utm при JS редиректе

Tags: javascript

После нажатия на определенный элемент, через n-ое количество секунд запускается редирект.
Очень важно,чтобы передавались utm метки, но весь хвост обрезает.

Код

```
document.getElementById('click1').onclick = function(event) {
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "https://sait.ru/";           
}, 2000); 
};
```

Я не программист. Кто может помочь в решении задачи?

Comment: что такое "utm метка"? и что значит "обрезает"?

Comment: После ссылке идут определенные параметры для метрики (может быть разное количество и разные обозначения). 
Пример
sait.ru/?utm_source=parametr1&utm_term=parametr2&utm_content=parametr3&utm_medium=parametr4

Comment: Сам хвост, который необходим для аналитики, теряется.
Хвост вида:
?utm_source=parametr1&utm_term=parametr2&utm_content=parametr3&utm_medium=parametr4

Comment: Так ты его и не передаёшь судя по коду ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Согласен.
В этом просьба помочь.

Comment: ну впиши вместо `https://sait.ru/`  строку вида `https://sait.ru/?utm_source=parametr1&utm_term=parametr2&utm_content=parametr3&utm_medium=parametr4`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Это не постоянные параметры. Они разные в зависимости от источника, с которого зашел посетитель.
Об этом я выше писал.
Этот хвост (utm метки) нужно с адресной строки браузера забирать и далее уже подставлять при редиректе.

Comment: получите эти параметры и подставьте

Comment: Умно! 
Особенно учитывая то,что выше написано,что я не программист.
Нет желания помочь - не тратьте время на умозаключения.

Comment: "Об этом я выше писал" --- нет не писал. Ты вообще ничего не писал, кроме как "мне нужно подставить utm для переадресации". Никакой подробной информации что это, откуда это берётся, что с этим детально делать - ты не писал. Засим рекомендация: правильно чётко **детально** сформулировать описание проблемы и написать её. На данный момент всё выглядит так: "мне нужно сделать то, что мне нужно. помогите"

Comment: почитайте тут, как получить "хвост" )) --  https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.fa43c80a-62d28e2f-08b90947-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: добавьте к  ```https://sait.ru/``` + ```window.location.search```

Comment: @soledar10  можно сразу писать `window.location.href` который берёт весь URL

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто перезагрузить страницу, достаточно написать

```
window.location.reload();
```